# How to change full width home page and post page you tube width hight?

Tags: css, wordpress

I tried my best but I couldn't make the following theme full width/screen by editing the CSS. And Single post wider so embedded video will be more width and height same as youtube video width and height? I'd be very much grateful if you could show me or give me a hint regarding this customization.

https://www.happythemes.com/demo/?theme=videonow

I'm using above theme on this website. `http://nepvideo.com`

You see the footer in the above theme(It's full width), how do I make the whole theme's body/container full width like the footer?

Note: I tried adding/removing margins/paddings etc.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site 
that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once 
the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a 
[Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that 
demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see 
[Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have to change to following

on line 896

```
/* Site Content */
.site-content {
  width: 100%; /*max-width: 1000px; */
  margin: 20px auto;
}
```

and on line 909 add max-width: 100px; and margin: 0 auto

```
/*--------------------------------------------------------------
# Featured Content
--------------------------------------------------------------*/
#featured-content {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks It's work but post single post page showing white space  embedded video is not set  please check below url http://nepvideo.com/?p=1455 .

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean